# is it possible to connect videomixer and rthp264pay in gstreamer?

Tags: merge, gstreamer

I'm working on a code to stream mosaic of videos in gstreamer and so far I have a big problem.

I can stream one `videotestsrc` but I'm trying now to use `videomixer` and can't use it with `rthp264pay`,it would be very useful to merge those two functionalities.

I would be glad if anyone could help me with that

Answer (score 0):

videomixer has src is **video/x-raw**.
rtph264pay has sink is **video/x-h264**

So if you want to connect videomixer and rtph264pay you need a h264-encoder to encode video-raw to h264 format, ex: x264enc,